# How to ask GNU GetText (dxGetText) to ignore certain properties of Delphi components (especially SQL texts)?

Tags: delphi, translation, gettext, delphi-2009

I am using GNU GetText for Delphi (http://dxgettext.po.dk/download https://sourceforge.net/projects/dxgettext/ with corrections for Windows 10 [dxgettext and Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162954/dxgettext-and-windows-10)) for extraction of translation *.po files from Delphi source code (*.pas and *.dfm files). Usually GetText grabs the texts from SQL queries as well, splits them into individual strings. The *.po file becomes messy and I am not sure whether translation will not be applied for the (undesirable) modification of SQL texts as well.

E.g. I am not using sole word "where" in captions in my program, but GetText extracts "where" occurences from alomst every SQL query text.

So - how can I ask GetText, that e.g. it does not extract text from `TIBQuery.SelectSQL`?

I am aware of the API functions like `procedure TP_GlobalIgnoreClass (IgnClass:TClass);`, but I guess that these functions acts only in runtime. But I would like to apply ignore to *.po file already.

Comment: You could also use a `ggexclude.cfg`, using `[exclude-form-class]` or `[exclude-form-class-property]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19450949/3836111 for that files documentation.

Comment: Where can I get more information about ggexclude.cfg? Is it some feature of dxgettext that is not mentioned in the dxgettext manual (that is quite extensive - 100 pages)? Google gives nothing.

Comment: There isn't much documentation to be found other than the in-file one that can be found in the answer I linked. It should be placed in the root folder of your generation process. IIRC you don't have to do anything else but place this file to make it work - but I'd have to check that again (can't atm)

Comment: "It should be placed in the root folder of your generation process" - it is sufficient to know, now I can experiment further. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could grab the source code of the dxgettext tool and modify it. If you do that, I am willing to review the changes and post them to the repository (I still have write access.). The source is located here: https://sourceforge.net/p/dxgettext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/dxgettext/dxgettext/